# Does "affirmative" mean "yes"

Tags: register

One hears people in the movies say "Affirmative" when they are speaking on a telephone or on   a walkie-talkie.  Does this word mean "yes"?  Can it be used instead of "yes"?

Comment: It does mean 'yes', definitely - but for common usage, really only if you're an android on a starship. Otherwise, I'd leave it to the military;)

Comment: @Tetsujin "Affirmative." (Note my avatar. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Confirmed, 'affirmative' is your go-to reply. Be careful not to ever use contractions, either, for the full 'Data'-style experience ;)

Comment: @tromano Affirmative :)

Comment: Supposed you have put forward a particular business proposal to someone and waiting for their reply then you could say that - 'Let your answer to our proposal be in the affirmative.' So it does mean 'yes'.

Answer (score 2):

*Yes* is an *affirmative* response, and when used as exclamations or interjections they have the same meaning, [as](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affirmative) [you](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/affirmative) [can](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/affirmative) [see](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/affirmative) [in](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/affirmative) [dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?q=affirmative%20define).

Since you're asking about registers, it's worth noting that *affirmative* as a response is decidedly formal. However, *yes* is so common that it's really acceptable in all registers, and you will likely raise some eyebrows if you respond with *affirmative*. The only times when *affirmative* is called for are during military or radio communication. This is because it's more difficult to mishear *affirmative*, and if you're also relaying a message for someone, it's unlikely to be mistaken as part of the message's content, due to its relative rarity.